# Visual Studio - Use Excel workbook that is in resources

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio

I´m having a problem in my vb.net program. I'm trying to create an application that the user inserts the data to the form and when click the button the application insert the data in the excel workbook.

I want that the excel workbook stay inside the application so I added it as a resource but when I try to open it using this code:

```
    Dim sPath As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetTempFileName
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(sPath, My.Resources.exceltemplate, False)
```

The application doens't recognize the "exceltemplate" (that I already added as a resource) as a resource. How can I fix it? Is there another way to do what I want?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the application doesn't recognize it as a resource?  Are you getting a compiler error, or a run-time error?  What is the error?  More info please.

Comment: Let me try to explain: I got to the resources folder -> right click -> add a existing item -> then add my excel workbook.

Comment: Yes, I understand that part.  My question was about how your application subsequently fails to recognize it.  What is the nature of this failure?  When does it fail -- compile time?  run time? -- and what is the error message?

Comment: Let me try to explain: I got to the resources folder -> right click -> add a existing item -> then add my excel workbook. So i want to use this workbook as a template that my application will fill with informations. Then I've researched and found that the code to use a excel template was that above.
But when I use: My.Resources.(type your resource) the compiler doesn't recognize my excel workbook but recognize the images I've added. So I think is a problem releated to the use of a workbook

Comment: The error message: 'exceltempalte' is not member of 'Resources'

Comment: When you type "My.Resources." do you get an intellisense menu giving you the resources available to you?  What's in that menu if no your "exceltemplate"?

Comment: Yes! I get an intellisense menu but my workbook that i've added in resources is not there! That menu only shows some images (.bmp) that i've added to the project.

Comment: I'm not sure then.  I would suggest you remove the resource and try adding it again.  Do you have any compiler warnings?

Comment: This the error msg `template2' is not declared. It may be inacessible due to its protection level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where was the error.
I deleted the excel workbook from paste "resources" so I added it again. But I added on this way: right click on My Project -> Properties -> Resources -> Add Existing Item.
Doing this way the program recognized the workbook as a resource.